# Doctrine get entity with item

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get the field of an entity that is associated with another .

My entity Offers has a last_offer field. 
Offers is related to the Products entity.

Then , with a consultation in my entity Products, I want to get the latest offer associated with the entity Offer.

Controller:

```
public function lastAction($key)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $last_offer = $em->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Products')->findOfferByKey($key);

    $response = new JsonResponse();

    return $response->setData($last_offer);
}
```

My repository:

```
public function findOfferByKey($key){
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $dql = 'SELECT pr, of FROM MyAppBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Products pr
                INNER JOIN pr.offers of
                WHERE pr.key = :key';

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter('key', $key)
            ->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

        return $query->execute();
    }
```

My routing:

```
last_offer:
    path:    /{key}/last_offer
    defaults: { _controller: "MyAppBundle:Products:last" }
```

But, this return an array.

I want to return only last_offer element.

Or to return the entity offers without being in an array.

Comment: Can'y you simply order descing your record primary key, and set limit to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifically telling doctrine to generate/return an array with this line

```
->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I *think* all you need to do is remove that line and doctrine will generate/return entities instead. *However*, you will get a [Collection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html) back, so make sure to take that into account. Perhaps something like

```
public function findOfferByKey($key) {

    $dql = 'SELECT pr, of FROM MyAppBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Products pr
            INNER JOIN pr.offers of
            WHERE pr.key = :key';

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameter('key', $key)
    ;

    $results = $query->execute();

    if (count($results) !== 1)
    {
         // It's up to you how to handle zero or multiple rows
    }

    return $results->current();
}
```

### EDIT

I see what's happening - I wasn't paying attention to your `SELECT` caluse. You're not selecting just the `last_offer` columns, you're selecting the entirety of the Products ***and*** Offers entities = `$results` is going to be an array of all of these together. In this scenario, `$query->execute()` *will* return an `array()` instead of a collection.

If you want to select just the `Offer` entities, you need to modify the SELECT

```
    $dql = 'SELECT of
            FROM MyAppBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Products pr
            INNER JOIN pr.offers of
            WHERE pr.key = :key';
```

But be wary that this still may return more than one row.

Comment: But if I want to return only the field last_offer as it should?

If i use your solution i receive the error: Call to a member function current() on a non-object.

Comment: And this? 

`$dql = 'SELECT pr, of.last_offer FROM MyAppBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Products pr INNER JOIN pr.offers of WHERE pr.key = :key;`

Comment: That will return something like this: `array(Product, 'value of last offer')` unless there are multiple matching rows in which case I think it would be more like `array(array(Product, 'value of last offer 1'), array(Product, 'value of last offer 2'))`

Comment: Best way:

`$dql = 'SELECT of.last_offer FROM MyAppBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Products pr
                INNER JOIN pr.offers of
                WHERE pr.key = :key';`

Comment: That will work, provided your `Offer` entity has a public property named `$last_offer` or a public getter named `getLast_offer()` since DQL operates on Entities and their properties, not column and table names.

Comment: Sure, it's what I want :) get that property.

This return: 

`[{"last_offer":{"date":"2015-05-27 16:20:45","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America\/New_York"}}]`

I could be alone with the property 'date' if do a for each in my controller, true?